# How to redraw ZXing QR code on TextChanged Event - Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**I'd like to redraw my QR Code every time a particular `TextChanged` event is triggered.**

The `ZXingBarcodeImageView` object gets drawn in the view when the page loads with the value `BarcodeValue` set in the XAML file like this:

```
<forms:ZXingBarcodeImageView 
       Margin="5,5,5,0"
       x:Name="QRCodeView"
       BarcodeFormat="QR_CODE" 
       BarcodeValue="-1" //this is the value of the QR code
/>
```

I have an `Entry` with a `TextChanged` event attached, which triggers a function `UpdateQRLabel`. This function should redraw the QRCode with the new value in `Entry`

```
<Entry
       x:Name="Message" 
       TextChanged="UpdateQRLabel"   
/>
```

If I change the `BarcodeValue` parameter after the QRCode has been drawn, it **DOES NOT** get redrawn automatically.

I need to force the **ZXingBarcodeImageView** object to redraw every time the `TextChanged` event is triggered.

**Question**

How do I force the `ZXingBarcodeImageView` to redraw when the `TextChanged` event is triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're using data-binding or not. Since you are using events I guess not, however, I did get it to work with data-binding. A sample repo can be found here: https://github.com/jfversluis/ZXingValueBinding

It comes down to this. Create a property which will hold your barcode value:

```
private string _barcodeValue = "-1";

public string BarcodeValue
{
    get { return _barcodeValue; }
    set
    {
        _barcodeValue = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(BarcodeValue)));
    }
}
```

The object holding this property needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. You could consider using PropertyChanged.Fody for these.

I have put this property in the code-behind of my page, this can also be a separate class. Now, change your barcode image view to this: `<forms:ZXingBarcodeImageView ... BarcodeValue="{Binding BarcodeValue}">`.

Whenever you set a new value to `BarcodeValue`, the value should change because the UI is notified because of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for answering another question of mine. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: No problem at all! Remember to mark it as an answer as well! :)

Comment: I get this error when I add that code `The event 'BindableObject.PropertyChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=`

Comment: Ah yeah I got that as well when using the code-behind as the `BindingContext` check out the sample repo. I added the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the event that comes with that manually. It seems that interface is implemented somewhere else in the partial class